# Can I configure Google DataFlow to keep nodes up when I drain a pipeline

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I am deploying a pipeline to Google Cloud DataFlow using Apache Beam. When I want to deploy a change to the pipeline, I drain the running pipeline and redeploy it. I would like to make this faster. It appears from the logs that on each deploy DataFlow builds up new worker nodes from scratch: I see Linux boot messages going by.

Is it possible to drain the pipeline without tearing down the worker nodes so the next deployment can reuse them?

Comment: Have you checked updating a pipeline?

Comment: @Iñigo yes, but it only works in special cases and the `--update` arg is [marked as experimental](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/options/pipeline_options.py#L669) in Beam's DataFlow SDK

Comment: Answering the original question, no, there's no way to do that. Updating should be the way to go. I was not aware it was marked as experimental (probably we should change that), but the update approach has not changed in the last 3 i have been using DF. About the special cases of update not working, supposing your feature existed, the workers would still need the new code, so no really much to save, and update should work in most of the other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rewriting Inigo's answer here:

Answering the original question, no, there's no way to do that. Updating should be the way to go. I was not aware it was marked as experimental (probably we should change that), but the update approach has not changed in the last 3 i have been using DF. About the special cases of update not working, supposing your feature existed, the workers would still need the new code, so no really much to save, and update should work in most of the other cases.